# SQL Server - resultado función en español

Tags: sql-server

estoy usando una función de sql server pero el resultado de fecha siempre me lo regresa en inglés, al momento de usarlo en un querie establezco el idioma a español antes de ejecutar y todos los resultados me los procesa en español menos el resultado de la función.

Ejemplo:

```
Set LANGUAGE Spanish
Select fecha, dbo.Ufn_substract_working_days(fecha, 6)
```

El primer campo lo regresa en español y el segundo no.

La función es esta:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Ufn_substract_working_days] (@DATE  DATE,
                                                    @NDAYS INT)
                                                    
returns DATE
  
  BEGIN
      IF @DATE IS NULL
        BEGIN
            RETURN NULL;
        END

     

      DECLARE @STARTDATE INT = 0
      DECLARE @COUNT INT = 0
      DECLARE @NEWDATE DATE=Dateadd(day, -1, @DATE)

      WHILE @COUNT < @NDAYS
        BEGIN
            IF Datepart(weekday, @NEWDATE) NOT IN ( 1 )
               AND @NEWDATE NOT IN (SELECT hdate
                                    FROM   xHolidays)
              SET @COUNT += 1;
                    SELECT @NEWDATE = Dateadd(day, -1, @NEWDATE),
                   @STARTDATE -= 1;
        END
         RETURN Dateadd(day, @STARTDATE, @DATE);

  END
```

Comment: Como sugerencia para futuras preguntas, incluye siempre datos de prueba, lo que debe obtener la consulta y lo que esta obteniendo

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está ocurriendo es algo como esto:

```
Set LANGUAGE Spanish
Select Fecha, dbo.Ufn_substract_working_days(Fecha, 5)
       from (select '04-12-2020' Fecha) T

Fecha       (No column name)
04-12-2020  2020-11-28
```

Explicación:

- `Fecha` es un columna tipo cadena, que ya viene con un formato Español, `dd-mm-yyyy`
- La cadena `Fecha` es procesada por tu función y convertida implícitamente en un `DATE`, la salida final es otro `DATE`
- Los datos tipo fecha se muestran por defecto con el formato universal ISO `yyyy-mm-dd` esto es independiente del `Set LANGUAGE Spanish`
- Para mostrar una fecha con un determinado formato, hay que transformarla en una cadena (el dato `date` o `datetime` no tienen ningún formato en particular)

---

```
Set LANGUAGE Spanish
Select Fecha, convert(varchar, dbo.Ufn_substract_working_days(Fecha, 5), 105)
       from (select '04-12-2020' Fecha) T


Fecha       (No column name)
04-12-2020  28-11-2020
```